# window not defined error while using reactJs, Redux and import sweetalert

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, sweetalert

Here is my code snippet looks somthing like this, i have the sweetalert in package.json.

```
import swal from 'sweetalert';  export function delete() {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    swal({
            title: "Delete API?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this API!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        });}
```

The error is in **public/server.js**

```
if(window.console){
```

window is not defined, this is realted to `sweetalert`.

I had this working for a while, but when i did clean npm run build it replaces the `server.js` and this new line of code is added to `server.js`

I saw some suggestions not to render it on server side when using react/redux but looking for a way not to load sweetalert package while rendering.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The original Sweetalert plugin is unsupported, take a look on [Sweetalert2](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2)

Comment: @limonte i tried sweetalert2 as well then i got document not defined error which is similar to the above. I saw you worked a lot on sweetalert2, i guess you own that package, can you help me with it when i'm using sweetalert2 in the similar manner it throwed an error saying document not found in public/server.js

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is react/redux is trying to render "sweetalert" when the webpackbuilds and goes over the generated public/server.js it couldn't find window and throwing error as undefined,  so just to stop server side rendering of sweetalert, i replaced

```
import swal from "sweetalert";
```

With

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const swal = isBrowser ? require('sweetalert') : undefined;
```

This worked for me i found it on some thread on github, what it does is stop rendering sweetalert on serverside. Hope this helps!!